# Unable to install IIS AspNetCoreModuleV2 in a dockerimage (and Azure Pipelines)

Tags: asp.net, docker, iis, azure-pipelines

I have a problem for few days now with the "dotnet hosting bundle" and AspNetCoreV2 IIS module in a dockerimage.

So, I creating a dockerimage with many IIS modules and requirements to execute our software. The dockerimage works good expect this AspNetCoreV2 module. When the container created, I check the modules installed with `Get-WebGlobalModule` and doesn't appear.
But, when I start the quiet (or passive) installation manualy, into the container, this module works and appear in the IIS Module list.

I tried many solutions to do that (multistage with aspnetcore Microsoft images, last version of dotnet_hosting_bundle.exe and many other, but same issue).

I tried to automatise the docker exec process to install this module manualy and commit it with Azure Pipelines and Windows agent in a VM, but doesn't work :(.
To try that, I use different way :

```
      docker stop mycontainer
      docker rm mycontainer
      docker run --name mycontainer -d -it $(containerRegistry)/$(container_requirement_name):v1.0.$(Build.BuildId)
      docker exec mycontainer powershell.exe -command Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Program Files\MySoftware\PowerShell\Installer.Prerequisites\dotnet-hosting-3.1.2-win.exe' -ArgumentList "/passive","/install","/norestart"  -PassThru -Wait
      docker stop mycontainer
      docker commit mycontainer $(containerRegistry)/$(container_requirement_name):v1.0.$(Build.BuildId).1
```

In the Start-Process, I can see :
[image]
The process is created but apparently not started

I also tried with : `cmd 'C:\Program Files\MySoftware\PowerShell\Installer.Prerequisites\dotnet-hosting-3.1.2-win.exe' /quiet /install`

This task in Azure Pipeline working without error, but when I download this new image (pushed after these instructions), the module doesn't appear in `Get-WebGlobalModule`

Also, the module is not presend into ProgramFiles

I don't really understand how can I install this module. All other modules working, expect this ...

Thanks you very much in advance for your advises.

Best

Comment: Please have a try setting the preference variables in powershell first.`powershell -Command $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'  $ProgressPreference = 'Continue'  $verbosePreference='Continue' `

Comment: Thanks ! With this commands, it working in Azure Pipelines with an Azure Agent (automatically assigned by the pipeline) but doesn't works with an custom Agent installed on a VM. It's strange.

Also, can you explain me quickly why it's working with this commands please ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the preference variables with below command fixed above issue.

`powershell -Command $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'  $ProgressPreference = 'Continue'`

The values of the preference variables affect how PowerShell operates and executes cmdLets. It might be because the default settings of the preference variables of the container that caused the PowerShell failing to complete the installation. You can override these preference variables in your script.

Please see [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-7.1#short-description) for more information about Preference Variables.

Comment: Thanks you very much for your explanation ! It working now